# updating Counter Strike: Source version to version

Tags: counter-strike-source

I want to update my CS:S from 1.0.0.33 to 1.0.0.34, but I cannot find any links or patches for download.  Where can I find one?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Patches to this game should be handled by Steam.

This is done by right clicking on the game in your Steam library and selecting *Properties*, and then selecting the *Updates* tab:

[image: Steam game properties, Update tab]

Check in your Steam settings that the game is set to auto-update, although the [version history](http://www.steampowered.com/platform/update_history/index.php?id=240) for the game suggests it's been at it's current version since September.